# Lost my passport and Schengen visa in Spain

Tags: visas, schengen, china, spain, singapore

I lost my passport and my schengen visa in Spain. How can I get a new schengen visa ASAP? I have already booked my flight which cost me **more than 800 euro** and my trip will start **next Tuesday December 16th.** All my flights were booked from budget airline and not refundable.

I am Chinese but study at a university in Singapore. I came to Madrid for an exchange program from September to December. I got my visa from the Embassy of Spain in Singapore. I already went to the Embassy of China in Madrid and they are helping me with my temporary passport now. I think that I should be able to get it within this week.

How can I get a new Schengen visa? Most importantly, who shall I contact? I have been to a lot of police stations but they are not very helpful.

Comment: Vital that you get and save the police reference number for reporting a lost/stolen passport. Vital.

Comment: Presumably you went to the embassy of China in Singapore, not in Madrid, for your New Chinese passport? Then you need to go to the embassy of Soain, they're the only ones who can do something about your visa.

Comment: Are your flights going to exit Schengen zone and enter it again?

Comment: It is within schengen area!! I m going to Copenhagen and Iceland

Comment: I went to the embassy of china in Madrid and they are processing the temporary document which serve the same function as passport now. Does anyone know the telephone number of the embassy of Spain in Madrid? I know this sounds weird but just want to ask the number to call so that I can tell them my problem

Comment: @EstherYanglanWang There is no embassy of Spain in Madrid, embassies represent foreign countries. You need to contact some sort of local department/agency/ministry/service in charge of immigration but unfortunately I don't know exactly how it works in Spain. You could perhaps check with the town administration or a Spanish consulate/embassy in your own country. With some luck, they might know who you need to contact.

Comment: @Relaxed, it's the police.

Answer (score 1):

For immediate advice I would suggest visiting a Oficina de Extranjeros, which is a local foreigners office.

There is a link below, but in Spanish

http://www.seap.minhap.gob.es/es/servicios/extranjeria/extranjeria_ddgg.html

Select the region you are in and it will give you a list

For you in Madrid I suggest the office below

I have used this office

> SEDE 5. OFICINA DE EXTRANJERÍA DE MANUEL LUNA - OFICINA DE INFORMACIÓN
>
> Información general
>
> Calle Manuel Luna, 29
>   28020 - Madrid
>
> Teléfonos:
>   91 272 95 00

They helped me with a resedencia permit.

If the can't help, they should know where you need to go.

Good luck

Comment: they are only in charge of renewing the visa. for my case they can't help. I went to the police station at aluche but they can only issue me a certificate which allow me to come back to madrid. They can't issue me visa to go anywhere.

Comment: I went to OFICINA DE EXTRANJERÍA DE MANUEL LUNA - OFICINA DE INFORMACIÓN this morning but they said they are only in charge of visa renewing. They can't really help me